# Is there a way to make an alternating positive and negative number sequence in Java?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I was wondering if there is a way to make an alternating positive and negative number sequence in Java using conditional statement and loop or nested loop. I would like to have my output like this: 1, -2, 3, -4, 5 and so on if they entered a higher number. This is what I have for now and it only prints positive numbers. Take note that I am also using scanner so that it can be customizable.

```
System.out.println("Enter a number:");
int num2 = scan.nextInt();  
for (int i = 1;i <= num2;i++) {
    System.out.print(i+" ");
}
```

Comment: Multiply the number by `(i % 2 == 0) ? -1 : 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just think about simple Math. The example you gave has *odd numbers* positive and *even numbers* negative - 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6...
So like Andy Turner commented:

`i * ((i % 2 == 0) ? -1 : 1.)`

So `%` is the modulus operator, it will give you the **remainder** of the divison, e.g., 2 / 2 is 1 with 0 remainder, 3 / 2 is 1 with 1 remainder.
The ternary operator `() ? true : false` evaluates the expression before the `?` and will yield the value before the colon if true, the value after the colon if false.

Now if you **don't** necessarily want this to be about even/odd numbers, you can just keep a multiplier around:

```
int num2 = scan.nextInt();  
for (int i = 1, sig = 1; i <= num2; i++, sig = sig * -1) {
    System.out.print(Integer.toString(i * sig));
}
```

Multiplying with -1 will flip the sign each time.